# Is it advisable to store blog-type (large) contents on a mysql db?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am building an admin page for our website using PHP. There's a part where we need to enter information about our product (widgets to be specific). Informations are like features, selling points, and faqs about the specific product. I've been thinking about using contentful but I don't think they have an API that I can use to save the data as contentful can only be managed on their platform, and access those data through API. We've been building our own admin UI, so we prefer if we can manage our own data in there.

So my main question is, I hope I get this far from being subjective, is it advisable to store blog-like (large) contents on a MySQL DB? If not, what is the best approach to doing this or database to use rather than using a CMS?

Answer (score 0):

I think that most blog sites and simiar do store that information in a SQL DB. Just use "text" instead of "varchar" and it shouldn't be any problems.

(This would've been better as a comment but I don't have 50 rep)